# R - xgboost hyperparameters tunning

Tags: r

trying to optimize xgboost and have the below code (data set is all numeric with the target variable and it is for the regression (0 - 1 values).

```
df_train <- train_raw

# set up the cross-validated hyper-parameter search
xgb_grid_1 = expand.grid(
  nrounds = 1000,
  eta = c(0.01, 0.001, 0.0001),
  max_depth = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10),
  gamma = 1,
  nround = 120,
  max_depth =1

)

# pack the training control parameters
xgb_trcontrol_1 = trainControl(
  method = "cv",
  number = 5,
  verboseIter = TRUE,
  returnData = FALSE,
  returnResamp = "all",                                                        # save losses across all models
  #classProbs = TRUE,                                                           # set to TRUE for AUC to be computed
  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
  allowParallel = TRUE
)

x = as.matrix(df_train %>% select(-target))

# train the model for each parameter combination in the grid, 
#   using CV to evaluate
xgb_train_1 = train(
  x = as.matrix(x),
  y = df_train$target,
  trControl = xgb_trcontrol_1,
  tuneGrid = xgb_grid_1,
  method = "xgbTree"
)
```

The error I got is

`Error: The tuning parameter grid should have columns nrounds, max_depth, eta, gamma, colsample_bytree, min_child_weight, subsample`

I am lost as to why my xgb_train_1 can not see xgb_grid_1. Any ideas please?

Comment: As I read that error message you are missing three of the necessary columns. How are you reading that message?

Comment: It does refer to existing columns as missing - this is how i read it.

Comment: Then I interpret that as saying it's "seeing" xgb_grid_1 ,... just not finding what it needs.